# Tab plugin for wordpress

Tags: tabs, wordpress, permalinks

I am searching for a wordpress tab plugin to display my posts with the following criteria

- The tab should load content for only the active tab(for most of the plugins it loads all the content for all tabs, increasing the loading time)
- Each time the post should reload, when inactive(other) tabs are clicked, rendering the content for the current tab only.
- Permalink support for tabs to call
- Support for inserting other custom short codes(other gallery short codes to insert in tabs.)

Reference site for tab: [zomato restaurant](http://www.zomato.com/chennai/restaurants/south/anna-salai/pizza-hut-65858)

[tab garb](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tabgarb/) plugin came close but i cannot add shortcode to it.

[wordpress post tabs](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-post-tabs) is a great plugin but loads everthing on the same page.

Is their any other plugin or a solution?